# Writing tool for documents with multiple authors

Tags: note-taking, collaboration, documentation-generator

I'm looking for a tool for teachers. They write assessments for their pupils. So each teacher writes one per pupil. The software should collect all single assessments and create one large document out of it. Furthermore it should be possible that they write on the document at the same time and without having conflicts.

When looking around I found [one question with answers](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25224/collaboration-platform-with-restricted-fields-roles-for-school-reports). However the proposed solutions don't allow collaboration and it seems to be quite complex for several hundred pupils.

I also tried to play around with wikis (MediaWiki and Dokuwiki). Also here all possible solutions I could think of were too complex.

I imagine a site where a teacher logs in and sees its pupils. The teacher writes an assessment for the pupils and the software creates a complete assessment per pupil.

Do you know of a solution which does (nearly) what I want? Which would you propose?

Comment: Google Docs might work. It might be best for each teacher to not see the other’s assessments.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention: Google Drive/Docs/etc. is not an option because of the possible privacy violations.

Comment: You can use Sqlite, Microsoft Access or LibreOffice Base.

Comment: Is it possible to collaboratively edit documents with MS Access or LibreOffice Base? Why did you suggest SQlite, but not MySQL, PostGres or other DBMS?